# How to match array, then echo value from array from the matched id's only?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I check if a value exists in a multidimensional array, then echo value from that match?

Would in_array work in this case?

```
$types = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id' => '10',
        'file' => 'bike.png',
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id' => '20',
        'file' => 'car.png',
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id' => '30',
        'file' => 'plane.png',
    )
);

$matches = array('10','20');

types   = 10, 20, 30
matches = 10, 20
```

Since 10 and 20 were matched, echo bike.png, and car.png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over your array and check if the product id is present in your second array.

```
foreach ($types as $sub)
{
   if(in_array($sub["id"],$matches))
   echo $sub["file"];
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/760426)**

Comment: You're welcome. Side-note: You don't need to put quotes around numbers

Comment: Sorry to bother, what if the $matches in this case is reporting as NULL as it's targeting a value from the array, although? I'd need a second foreach inside the first, but I wouldn't be able to use in_array in that case then, am I correct? https://eval.in/760459

Comment: Then you can modify the condition to also check if $matches is an array, like `if(is_array($matches) &&   in_array($sub["id"],$matches))`

Comment: Alright, that I understood.. I've tried including another foreach to take care of the $getProducts array, but right now it's only returning 1 id file only https://eval.in/760508

Comment: Because you are using a `return` which returns after its first execution. Build an array/string in that loop and return after